# Return a default value in query get of Python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I use Python Bottle and I want to retrieve a few parameters from url. Is there any way to add a default value IF there isn't a value in the parameter?

Example:

```
myvalue = bottle.request.query.get('value')
if not myvalue:
   myvalue = default_value
```

Instead of this, I am looking for something similar to Python Dictionaries:

```
dict.get(key, default=None)
```

Comment: `bottle.request.query` is a subclass of `DictMixin`, so its `get` method should behave just like `dict.get`.

Comment: I didn't know that. I will try it and if it is correct, please add it as an answer, so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1):

The bottle way is actually more flexible. You need to setup two routes and a default value for the parameter for this to work:

```
@bottle.route('/hello')
@bottle.route('/hello/<who>')
def show(who="world"):
    return "Hello, " + who
```

Comment: I am asking about query parameters, not subroutes. For example `/home?value=1;value2=2` etc. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: My bad. See @Blender's comment on the question, it sure seems logical ;-)